How to avoid 404 Error on Vercel Deployment?
i have the following files (HTML, CSS, and Json file) in github repo
enter image description here
nonetheless I keep hitting the 404 error
404: NOT_FOUND
Code: NOT_FOUND
ID: sin1::pfczf-1713483028059-f17ff582de90
Logs are without errors and warnings as well
enter image description here
here's the code in my son file (dont know if this is all that I need)
{ "routes": 

[{ "src": "/[^.]+",
"dest": "/",
"status": 200 }] }
